# Installed Tailwind in my React project but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: reactjs, installation, tailwind-css, styling

The installation finished without any errors, yet, it doesn't seem to be working.

None of the Styles is being implemented even though the following configuration seems to be accurate:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Below is the link to the installation process I followed:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: can you put your project on Sandbox?

Comment: show us your project file structure

Comment: Can you explain how i get in Sandbox? Filestruture can you lock here: https://ibb.co/n7SHbGS

Comment: Have you tried installing CSS?

Comment: What do you mean if I have CSS installed, it's automatically there yes tailwindcss i have istallled is included in package.json